# Why is the actual data from my SQL table not showing?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am attempting to put data from an SQL table from a remote server in a dropdown list. I need the information to update as the DB updates.

This is my Controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SimulationDBEntities"].ToString());

    public List<QuoteTechModel> List()
    {
        var obj = conn.Query<QuoteTechModel>("USE SimulationDB; SELECT a.QTName As QTName FROM QuoteTechInfo a").OrderByDescending(a => a.QTName).ToList();

        List<QuoteTechModel> result = new List<QuoteTechModel>();            

        foreach (var row in obj)
        {
            QuoteTechModel model = new QuoteTechModel();
            model.QTName = row.QTName;
            result.Add(model);
        }

        return (result);
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.techList = List();
        return View();
    } 

}
```

This is my Model

```
public class QuoteTechModel
{
    public string QTName { get; set; }
}
```

This is the part of my view

```
<select class="form-control" name="SelectQuoteTech" id="SelectQuoteTech" style="width:20%">
    <option value=" ">@ViewBag.techList</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Do you get any data in the `obj` variable? You're also not `Open()`-ing your sql connection.

Comment: You will have to have a javascript function that is set to go off every x seconds.  It will need to ajax to an action result tied to a partial view that contains your list box.  On success in your ajax call, update the html of your view with the html that came back from your ajax call.

Comment: sticking the whole list of objects into one option tag does not make a lot of sense. Did you not mean to loop through it and create lots of options?

Comment: I looped through the option tag and opened the sql connection and it is now showing me        "System.Collections.Generic.List'[QuoteTechList.Models.QuoteTechModel]   "          numerous times

Comment: yes well you probably want to use one of the actual properties from it, like an ID or description, not the whole object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was because I was trying to call the ViewBag as a whole instead of one thing from it. There was also some things in the controller I didn't need. Thanks guys!

Controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SimulationDBEntities"].ToString());

    public List<QuoteTechModel> List()
    { 
     return conn.Query<QuoteTechModel>("USE SimulationDB; SELECT a.QTName As Name FROM QuoteTechInfo a").ToList();
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.techList = List();
        return View();
    } 

}
```

View

```
<select class="form-control" name="SelectQuoteTech" id="SelectQuoteTech" style="width:20%">
    @foreach (var row in ViewBag.techList)
     {
       <option value="">@row.Name</option>
     }
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding a "Go" After the USE SimulationDB;? It seems you are trying to select a database. So you must excecute the batch before you can make any query against that db.